# my RPi connt connect to the internet even it is connect to the network

Tags: raspbian, ssh, connection, internet

[image]

[image]

as in the prev images 
the RPi is connected to the internal network 
and i can control it via ssh and it work well

put it cant connect the net or ping as in the images

what can i do ?? to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

> So try this. `sudo route add default gw <ip-of-your-router>`

i had found that answer from this page and worked with me 
[Connected to 2 networks cant access the internet](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19727/connected-to-2-networks-cant-access-the-internet)